# Checking user online status

Tags: mysql, pdo, status

I'm want tot check the user online status and have constructed a page from a number of sources I have read. I am still not able to get the desired results. Perhaps someone can look at my current code and let me know what is wrong with this part? The below code is the code the checks for a users online status, and I am also current getting the following error message:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::prepare() in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\online_status.php on line 11`

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/dbconfig.php');
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");



#RETURN A LIST OF WHICH USERS ARE INDICATED AS ONLINE IN THE TABLE 
            $stmtonline = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM sys_members'); 
            $stmtonline->execute;   
            $foundRows = $stmtonline->prepare("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();            

    if($foundRows->rowCount())
        {
        echo $foundRows->rowCount();
        }



if($row_count=="0")
        {


#INSERT THE USER INTO THE ONLINE_USERS TABLE IF THEY DO NOT EXIST
            $stmtinsrt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO sys_online_users (memberID, username, last_active) VALUES (:memberID, :username, :last_active)');
            $stmtinsrt->execute(array(
                ':memberID' => $_SESSION['memberID'],
                ':username' => $_SESSION['username'],
                ':last_active' => $timestamp                
            ));
            $id = $db->lastInsertId('memberID');
        }
        else 
        {
#UPDATE THE USER'S CURRENT STATUS IN THE TABLE IF THE DO EXIST
            $stmtupd = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO sys_online_users (memberID, username, last_active) VALUES (:memberID, :username, :last_active)');
            $stmtupd->execute(array(
                ':memberID' => $_SESSION['memberID'],
                ':username' => $_SESSION['username'],
                ':last_active' => $timestamp                
            ));
            $id = $db->lastInsertId('memberID');
        }   





?>
```

Comment: Where is defined `$db`? `$db` must be instance of `PDO`, not `PDOStatement`.

Comment: $db is defined in my config files

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$stmtonline->prepare` to `$db->prepare`

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got my query to work, by simplify it quite a bit.. ere is the result that worked for me:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);     require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/dbconfig.php');    $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    {



        $stmtinsrt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO sys_page_hit (memberID, username, last_active) VALUES (:memberID, :username, :last_active) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_active= :last_active');
        $stmtinsrt->execute(array(
            ':memberID' => $_SESSION['memberID'],
            ':username' => $_SESSION['username'],
            ':last_active' => $timestamp                
        ));
        $id = $db->lastInsertId('memberID');
    }
```

?>